# Use the long reserved word as a variable name in C#

Tags: c#

a bit of an unusual one.. but I was wondering if anyone knew how I could declare a reserved word as a variable. I have the following code, but it does not like my use of the long variable name. I know I could rename it, but for instrest sakes I would like to know if this is at all possible.

```
private string lat;
private string long;

public string Lat 
{ 
    get
    {
        return lat;                
    }
}

public string Long 
{ 
    get
    {
        return long;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using the somewhat longer but more descriptive `latitude` and `longitude`.

Comment: Consider not making latitude and longitude strings; they are logically angles, not strings.

Comment: Consider deserializing or automapping a response object from a poorly-designed API that didn't consider reserved words (e.g. response.location.long)!

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Yes, you can if you *really* want to:

```
private string @long;
```

The actual *name* of the variable (as reported by reflection etc) is just `long`; the `@` sign tells the compiler to ignore the fact that it's also a keyword.

I would very strongly advise against this, however.

Comment: I'd agree. They're reserved for a reason. Talk about code clarity and maintainability, let alone bug resolution and you'll see why.

Comment: I saw an answer posted to this site containing a code snippet where *every* identifier was prefixed with @.  Quite a flak attack on that one.  Haven't seen him back.

Comment: Besides, as far as I know, the C# guidelines recommend not abbreviating words -- so `long` should rightfully be `longitude`. Longitude is not that long of a word, regardless.

Comment: "The actual name of the variable (as reported by reflection etc) is just long" -- Has this changed in C# 7.0 or somewhere along the way?  I can't get it to work, it still complains about long being reserved when I try to use it, and intellisense is suggesting @long.  I'm not really planning on keeping this name, I'm just curious.

Comment: @rory.ap: What do you mean by "when I try to use it"? If you're trying to use it from C#, you still need to use `@long`, but when you fetch it via reflection it should show up as `long`. Maybe it's worth asking a new question.

Comment: I found this syntax useful to read a _dynamic_ (ExpandoObject) that came from a JSON object that had a property called `params`.  Couldn't write `obj.params` to access it because `params` is a reserved word in c#, so had to write `obj.@params` to access it.

Comment: what about razor?

Comment: @Serge: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking. I suggest you ask a new, detailed question showing what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what problems you're running into.

Comment: I thought, with Razor would be different, as `@` symbol represents a reserved one in Razor... However, Razor seems to be intelligent enought to understand that `@readonly` is not a try to dispay the value of a variable, named "readonly", but actually to output the "readonly" to html output `<input @readonly='readonly'>`

Comment: sometimes this is needed to received a json payload for example from a webapi request, and the payload contains reserved field names like 'object', just faced this when subscribing to a webhook from Facebook Messenger

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam: Every JSON serializer I've used has allowed you to use an idiomatic name in the C#, and use an attribute to specify the name to use in JSON. I would strongly advise doing that to separate the wire format from code.

Comment: @JonSkeet good point, just went through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0#customize-individual-property-names

Answer (score 11):

As others have mentioned, you can escape a reserved word with `@`.

In your example you don't really need to, I would write the property like this:

```
private string _long;
public string Long 
{ 
    get
    {
        return _long;
    }
}
```

And the underscore and the capital L make it compile.

But it's kind of a tradition to call them Lat and **Lon**, or even better: Latitude and Longitude.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. Using the @ symbol.
This will work, for example: `private string @long;`
Doing this is highly not recommended, but it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer I know as I would steer clear of using reserved words as variable names, but if you insist then at least use the following:

```
private string lat;
private string @long;

public string Lat 
{ 
    get
    {
        return this.lat;                
    }
}

public string Long 
{ 
    get
    {
        return this.long;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be late to this party, but I thought I would throw in another place where using a reserved word as a variable name is a good idea!!

I am writing a web control, where I want one of the properties to be "class" in a similar manner as other elements have a "class" property.

So, indeed I will make my property be: "public string @class {get{} set{}}"

Comment: Property names by convention are capitalized. Besides, the standard name for that property is [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.className).