# What does the @ (At sign) symbol do to a variable? i.e. @variable name?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I (sadly) came across some old c# .NET 4.8 code that I wrote and I noticed a typo.  The code has been functioning fine in production for many years, but I was wondering if there is a difference between

`static public DataTable GetReportIDRange(int BeginningID, int @EndingID)`

and

`static public DataTable GetReportIDRange(int BeginningID, int EndingID)`

I removed the @ and it is still working fine.

Comment: @ allows a reserved word to be used as a variable name, ignored if not needed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787716/use-the-long-reserved-word-as-a-variable-name-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ allows a reserved keyword to be used as a variable name

---

```
static DataTable GetReportIDRange(int BeginningID, int @static)
{
   return null;
}
```

but in your case, you have to check if "EndingID" is being declared as some specific type  or keyword.

Normally it is always says to avoid using @ with parameters or variables but, we can have situations where third party API requesting to pass a parameter with reserved keywords, for example, lets say some API need an input and variable name has to be "event" , which is reserved keyword in C# in that case @ is helpful.

hope this clears the things in better way.

Comment: Which is almost always a confusing thing to do.

Comment: @EricJ., agree with you, but sometime you have to pass this into some third party REST API, where these apis are written in languages which doesn't have this keyword as special keyword. in that case can use @